# TCPServer remove any vowel (a, e, i, o, u) in the sentence S. Dewolizing the sentence "Hello World!" yields " Hll Wrld!"

Tags: java

I'm doing a TCPClient and TCPServer program, I want to delete the (a, e, i, o, u) in the message we got from client, then show the new message in server page.
I want to delete (a, e, i, o, u) in my TCPServer.java file, to show the message without aeiou.
But when I do compile, message.append("") and message.append(c) showed error. Could I know why and how to fix it? Thank you.

```
import java.net.*;  // for Socket, ServerSocket, and InetAddress
import java.io.*;   // for IOException and Input/OutputStream


public class myFirstTCPServer {

   private static final int BUFSIZE = 32;   // Size of receive buffer

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   
      if (args.length != 1)  // Test for correct # of args
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Port>");
   
      int servPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   
      // Create a server socket to accept client connection requests
      ServerSocket servSock = new ServerSocket(servPort);
   
      int recvMsgSize;   // Size of received message
      byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];  // Receive buffer
   
      for (;;) { // Run forever, accepting and servicing connections
         Socket clntSock = servSock.accept();     // Get client connection
      
         System.out.println("Handling client at " +
            clntSock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " on port " +
                 clntSock.getPort());
                 //code test
         InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(clntSock.getInputStream());
         BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(input);
         String message = bf.readLine();
         
         //replace
         for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char c = message.charAt(i);
            if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c =='u') {
               message.append("");
            }
            else {
               message.append(c);
            }
         }
         
         //output message
         System.out.println("Message with change:" + message);
      
      //my code above
         InputStream in = clntSock.getInputStream();
         OutputStream out = clntSock.getOutputStream();
         
      
         
      
         // Receive until client closes connection, indicated by -1 return
         while ((recvMsgSize = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1)
            out.write(byteBuffer, 0, recvMsgSize);
            
       
            
      
         clntSock.close();  // Close the socket.  We are done with this client!
      }
      /* NOT REACHED */
   }       
}
```

Comment: Don't just say "there is an error". What is the exact error message? Error messages contain important information about what the problem is.

Comment: Also, something like `message.append(...)` by itself will do nothing. `String` objects are immutable; calling `append` on a `String` will not modify the original string.

Comment: Actually, there is no `String#append()` method. At least from what I know.

Answer (score 0):

`String is immutable` - This means you can't modify the value you store in a string using append operation . `append()` is usually used with `StringBuilder` which is a mutable version (you can modify the content).

In your case , instead of `append()`  , try using `concat()` . `concat(string)` will add the contents to the end of the existing string .

So your code should look like

```
            if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c =='u') {
               message.concat("");
            }
            else {
               message.concat(c);
            }
```

Comment: In the first part of your answer, you say that String is immutable, and then in the code example, you try to modify the string. `concate` method returns a new string instance. You could just use `+` to achieve the same.